# How to store [String] or [Int] in react-native realm

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I've read online where in Android/iOS I should inherit from RealmObject and create my own RealmString to use as my objectType in a list.

What's the approach in react-native?  I can't find any code samples on how to handle this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same strategy in react-native:

```
var intObject = {
  name: 'intObject',
  properties: { value: 'int' }
};

var intListObject = {
  name: 'intListObject',
  properties: { 
    'intList': { type: 'list', objectType: 'intObject' } }
};

var realm = new Realm({schema: [intObject, intListObject]});

var listObject = realm.create('intListObject', { 
  intList: [{value: 0}, {value: 2}, ...]
});

var value = listObject.intList[1].value; // 2
```

We plan to support arrays of primitive types without the extra abstraction but there isn't yet an eta for this feature.

Comment: Not really ideal at the moment. Is there a method to support serializing data to a string before it's written? Something like a custom serialization step?

Comment: You could always use Array.join and String.split

Comment: @Ari using above solution makes multiple entries in db when I use create method with update true. Any solutions to that?

Comment: If you make the `value` property a primary key for `intObject` then it should reuse existing `intObjects` rather than creating new objects when setting the `update` flag to true.