# Storing arrays in react-native realm

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I cant seem to store an array from a json to my realm database.
Lets say the json that was returned to me is:

```
  contact: 
      { 
          name: 'Test Name',
          contactDetails: [ '4354354', '099324' ] 
      },
```

How can I insert contactDetails into realm?

Ive tried creating a custom object like this according to this [How to store [String] or [Int] in react-native realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210728/how-to-store-string-or-int-in-react-native-realm):

```
class stringObject extends Realm.Object {}
    stringObject.schema = {
     name: 'stringObject',
      properties: { value : 'string' }
     };
```

And tried adding this to the schema:

```
  contactDetails: {type: 'list', objectType: 'stringObject'}
```

But it cant be inserted into realm. I tried emptying the value in properties for my stringObject but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lists in Realm contain objects so you need to transform you JSON to the correct form before insertion. For the schema you provided you need to transform `contactDetails` to represent an array of valid `StringObject` objects before calling `realm.create`:

```
contactDetails: [ '4354354', '099324' ]
```

to

```
contactDetails: [ { value: '4354354' }, { value: '099324' } ]
```

You could do this using `Array.map` with something like:

```
json.contactDetails = json.contactDetails.map( s => ({ value: s }) );
```

Comment: If the map function returns you an array of undefined objects, try this: `json.contactDetails.map(s => { return { value: s }});`

Comment: This would work as well : `json.contactDetails.map(s => ({ value: s }));`  

Normal {} as in the answer represents a function body; while surrounding with () is evaluated as an expression

Answer (score 6):

In the properties of your schema:

```
contactDetails: { type: 'string?[]' },
```